# Does SE use Common Core math?

Tags: discussion, bug

I'm curious about the math used in the review queues.  If you review the limit of 20 posts per day in any queue, the week total shows as 160 (which implies 8 days in a week).  Does somebody need to "anchor the 1" or something?  (For readers unfamiliar with Common Core math, an [explanation](http://www.lonelyconservative.com/2014/09/common-core-lesson-how-to-add-96/) of this term).

One place you can see this is on the [review queues](https://superuser.com/review) page.  If you hover on a reviewer avatar, it shows the count of their reviews for the day, week, month, and total. The Close Votes queue tends to stay pretty large, so it isn't unusual for some reviewers to max out 20 each day.  A snapshot from my own summary:

[image: review stats]

Comment: @Sally http://superuser.com/review and hover over an avatar.

Comment: +1 for making fun of `common core`.  Some background: **I have multiple degrees( 2 B.S. and 1 M.S. ) that require a great deal of math, I was even only 6 credits away from a math minor, and `common core` confuses even me.**

Comment: Thanks for the link to the common core maths, I'd never heard of it. You unlearn something every day!

Comment: Reminds me of New Math.

Comment: @Synetech I thought it was *new math*.

Comment: Oh god.. I nearly vomited while watching that [common core video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uc3Pv5Q_AdA).

Comment: I'm not sure how this is confusing, at all. This is absolutely no different than carrying numbers, you're just going down instead of up.

Comment: I've generally found that the only people with a problem with Common Core math, already know math and are mad that its different. Most of the people I've encountered that are actually involved in the teaching of math to children are generally supportive, other than that they must first come to terms with it before they can teach it.

Comment: No, but their computers run a Pentium P5 800 nm 5V

Comment: Protip: Common Core is actually [standards](http://www.corestandards.org/read-the-standards/), all of the insane things you see are people who don't understand either math *or* the standards trying to teach both. And a massive industry sprung up foisting "curriculum" that's about as useful as most CS "certifications".

Comment: Math minor here. Common Core is STILL confusing even *with* the 6 extra credits. @Ramhound

Comment: @FrankThomas Although Common Core tries to teach the kind of shortcuts that people who are "good at math" tend to discover intuitively, I think we've all heard the horror-stories that – especially for kids who already knew some math before before seeing CC (say they got tutored privately with an aim to put them ahead) – they may already have a **different** set of *equally-effective* shortcuts which they may now get punished for or barred from using. I don't think most instructors *want* to teach it like a religion, but I believe a fair number are pressured to do so from the top.

Comment: Geez.  This thread has turned into a monster, and the actual question has taken a back seat.  Maybe I should have based my lame humor on something else.  :-)

Comment: @WayneWerner - Again;  Engineer here;  There is nothing standard about common math.  But perhaps I like to use the "old school" method to divide numbers.. I don't even know WHAT they call that division in Common Core.

Comment: @Ramhound the core standards just state that you need to [understand what division is]( http://www.corestandards.org/Math/Content/5/NBT/B/6/). Can you take a figure (e.g. a square), say that it has 4 units, and dividing it in half gives you two? Congrats, you understand common core math. Would you agree that it's important to grok that's what 4/2=2 *actually* means? All the insanity you see is usually someone trying to make a buck by making things extra complicated, and it pisses me off.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my guess:

A week is 168 hours. However, a week need not coincide with the calendar week that starts and ends at midnight Stack Exchange time. Reviews refill at 00:00 UTC, and in some time zones, this occurs during waking hours. For example, on the East Coast of the United States, it happens soon after the evening TV news.

1. Review 20 posts on Monday at 23:00 UTC
2. Review 20 more posts on Tuesday at 01:00 UTC
3. Review 20 posts on Wednesday at 01:00 UTC
4. Review 20 posts on Thursday at 01:00 UTC
5. Review 20 posts on Friday at 01:00 UTC
6. Review 20 posts on Saturday at 01:00 UTC
7. Review 20 posts on Sunday at 01:00 UTC
8. Review 20 posts on Monday at 01:00 UTC
9. View health

The time between 23:00 UTC on Monday and 01:00 UTC the following Monday is 146 hours, which is shorter than the 168 hours in a week.

To test this guess, view the user's review count once an hour. If it decreases other than at midnight UTC, the query is based on a 168-hour sliding window.

Another possibility is that it works like "Recent Changes" on a smaller MediaWiki site. "Past 7 days" means back to midnight UTC of the current day plus the previous 7 days.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that, also. But all actions happen in sync at 00:00 UTC. The counter is reset for "today", and the oldest day drops off the week. So if the counters show day/week as 20/160, at 00:00 UTC, it becomes 0/140 (and a maximum of 20 can be added until the next 00:00 UTC).

Comment: Your second theory could explain an 8 day week (first time I've seen that logic).